# Convert Android.net.Uri to Java.io.inputStream

Tags: java, android

I want to pass the image taken from the gallery of my phone to my java code through the Android Uri. Because Java.IO requires an File or java URL or java inputStream, how i can convert android Uri to inputStream?

However every time i am getting an exception.

i tried using this code to convert imageUri of my image data to `inputStream`.I can assure you that `imageUri` has valid content because i can watch the picture in `imageView`.
Also maybe if there is easier converting to java URL i have no problem with that. 
Thank you

````
    InputStream myimage = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
      LoadImageApp Image = new LoadImageApp( myimage );```



//code that passes content to imageUri.It is working fine.
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
             imageUri = data.getData();    
             imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
         }
 }
````

stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4819)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20152)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5572)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4819) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20152) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5572) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/imageio/ImageIO;
        at com.example.lib.LoadImageApp.<init>(LoadImageApp.java:66)
        at kostas.sgong.Main_Menu.onClickStart(Main_Menu.java:75)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4819) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20152) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5572) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.imageio.ImageIO" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/kostas.sgong-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.example.lib.LoadImageApp.<init>(LoadImageApp.java:66) 
        at kostas.sgong.Main_Menu.onClickStart(Main_Menu.java:75) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4819) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20152) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5572) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.imageio.ImageIO
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

Comment: "However everytime i am getting an exception" -- edit your question and post the stack trace. We cannot help you otherwise, as we have no idea what is going wrong. Also, where is `imageUri` coming from?

Comment: Sorry i am new developer. Posting now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/imageio/ImageIO;
```

You are attempting to use a Java class that does not exist in Android. Since your app compiled, this is probably coming from some library that you are using, where that library is not designed for use on Android.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But even if i added LoadImageApp to a java module in android studio and setup to run with JDK?

Comment: @Mathew: Android does not have this class. You cannot change that.